# como fazer radiobutton editavel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Seguinte, vou ter que adicionar radiobuttons dinamicamente, nisso elas vão ter que poder escrever. Elas vem como label ne? Eu precisava poder conseguir editar essa label, poderia ser uma text tambem, o importante é conseguir adicionar a radiobutton e o usuario poder escrever o que quiser na label

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Obrigada por responder Junior, só uma duvida. meu html ta assim:

```
                  <div class="form-group esconder" id="id_2">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="multipla-escolha">
                       <label class="" for="orderBy">Pergunta</label>
                       <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Pergunta">
                       <div class="container">
                          <div id="radios">
                             <div>
                                <input type="radio" value="teste" name="data">
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <button id="add">+</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

e quando renderiza ele já traz 2 radio, e quando eu clico em qualquer coisa, ele adiciona mais radios, sabe o que pode ser?

```js
function loadEditLabel() {
  // Salva o novo input saindo do campo ou apertando enter
  $('[contenteditable="true"]').focus().select().keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.key == 'Enter') { // Checa se a tecla digitada foi o Enter
      $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML); // Colocar o value do input com o texto digitado
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', false); // Desabilita o campo de edição
    }
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML);
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
  });
}

$('#add').click(function() {
  html = '<div>';
  html += '<input type="radio" value="" name="data">';
  html += '<label contenteditable="true"></label>';
  html += '</div>';
  
  $('#radios').append(html); // Adiciona o novo input dentro da div radios
  
  loadEditLabel(); // Carrega o radio para a edição
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radios">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="teste" name="data">
    <label>Teste</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="teste2" name="data">
    <label>Teste2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add">+</button>
```

---

eu vou adicionar um print, pois simulando pelo jsfiddle não acontece o mesmo erro.
Só pra entender, ele tá pegando todos os clicks antes mesmo de chegar na tela, e vai adicionando os radio.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function loadEditLabel() {
  // Salva o novo input saindo do campo ou apertando enter
  $('[contenteditable="true"]').focus().select().keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.key == 'Enter') { // Checa se a tecla digitada foi o Enter
        $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML); // Colocar o value do input com o texto digitado
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false); // Desabilita o campo de edição
      }
    })
    .blur(function() {
      $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML);
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
    });
}

$('#add').click(function() {
  html = '<div>';
  html += '<input type="radio" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" value="teste" name="data">';
  html += '<input type="text" placeholder="Nova Entrada">';
  html += '</div>';

  $('#radios').append(html); // Adiciona o novo input dentro da div radios

  loadEditLabel(); // Carrega o radio para a edição
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radios">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" value="teste" name="data"><input type="text" value="Opção 1">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add">+</button>
```

Comment: por favor, coloque algum trecho de código que você já fez para esclarecer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim também:

```js
function loadEditLabel() {
  // Salva o novo input saindo do campo ou apertando enter
  $('[contenteditable="true"]').focus().select().keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.key == 'Enter') { // Checa se a tecla digitada foi o Enter
      $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML); // Colocar o value do input com o texto digitado
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', false); // Desabilita o campo de edição
    }
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML);
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
  });
}

$('#add').click(function() {
  html = '<div>';
  html += '<input type="radio" value="" name="data">';
  html += '<label contenteditable="true"></label>';
  html += '</div>';
  
  $('#radios').append(html); // Adiciona o novo input dentro da div radios
  
  loadEditLabel(); // Carrega o radio para a edição
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radios">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="teste" name="data">
    <label>Teste</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="teste2" name="data">
    <label>Teste2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add">+</button>
```

OBS.: Foi testado no Chrome Versão 59.0

Answer (score 2):

Você quer dizer alguma coisa nessa linha? O label pode ser um input de texto?

```html
<h3>Sexo:</h3>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" name="gender" value="male"> <input type="text" placeholder="Masculino"><br>
  <input type="radio" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" name="gender" value="female"> <input type="text" placeholder="Feminino"><br>
</form>
```

Utilizando o JS fornecido pelo [@JuniorNunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212285/62465) você poderia também fazer alguma coisa nessa linha:

```js
function loadEditLabel() {
  // Salva o novo input saindo do campo ou apertando enter
  $('[contenteditable="true"]').focus().select().keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.key == 'Enter') { // Checa se a tecla digitada foi o Enter
        $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML); // Colocar o value do input com o texto digitado
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false); // Desabilita o campo de edição
      }
    })
    .blur(function() {
      $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML);
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
    });
}

$('#add').click(function() {
  html = '<div>';
  html += '<input type="radio" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" value="teste" name="data">';
  html += '<input type="text" placeholder="Nova Entrada">';
  html += '</div>';

  $('#radios').append(html); // Adiciona o novo input dentro da div radios

  loadEditLabel(); // Carrega o radio para a edição
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radios">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" value="teste" name="data"><input type="text" value="Opção 1">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add">+</button>
```

Comment: Oi Leon, funcionou seu codigo tambem!! só caiu no mesmo problema que o do Junior. Estou tentando entender o porque

Comment: @IsabellaMeirelles Não consigo simular o seu problema aqui? Alguma chance de você usar um de nossos códigos e compartilhar o erro aqui?

Comment: Consegui resolver!! Só uma coisa, eu adicionei um botão remover conforme: https://jsfiddle.net/71hmxrr8/, só que ele não funciona, nesse exemplo que vcs me passaram, teria que ser criado de outra forma?